# undefined reference to " `function` in the network device interface to the userspace."

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, android-networking

I want to use the network device interface exported by the network driver module. This is my program devget.c

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<linux/netdevice.h>

  void main(void)
  {
     struct net_device* device;

     device = dev_get_by_name("eth0");
     if (device == NULL)
         printf("device is NULL\n");
     else
         printf("This is a success story\n");
   }
```

I am cross compiling this. undefined reference to `dev_get_by_name'. Now this function is defined as a prototype in the /linux/netdevice.h file . I compile this with agcc giving the include paths in the script.

Comment: It seems that 'dev_get_by_name' is not included in the kernel.

Comment: Question is how to get the network device interface , So I can call the network API `s for the kernel in my device. I need to give the kernel headers /inlcude files that will have the prototypes for this dev_get_by_name. I am compiling this for android OS , I include the kernel withing the OS and give path to the kernel include during the compilation such as agcc getdev.c -o getdev -I android/kernel.

Comment: from user space, you cannot access the net_device structure. You should use some standard interfaces to configurate your network (ethtool, ifconfig). Otherwise you should write code in kernel instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be building a user space program, rather than a kernel module.

User space programs can't use kernel functions. They can only use functions from libc or other libraries.

You'll need to compile your code as a kernel module.
This changes several things - you don't have a `main` function (instead you have `init_module`, which isn't the same), and the compilation process is different (not just `gcc -o myprog myprog.c`).

I suggest you read a basic book about kernel development.